# How does Salesforce assign instances to orgs?

Tags: developer-org, instance

I am curious to know on what basis salesforce assigns orgs specially developer orgs. I have oldest dev org in ap7, then several on ap5 and recent one at eu5. Is this based on geographical location where the IP of sign up belongs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the instance number part - the ...7 vs ...5 allocation - I presume you are allocated to the instance that has most spare capacity at the time the org is created. Generally, the numbers go up but based on your experience, not always.

Capacity balancing (and perhaps for other operational reasons too) means that occasionally your org may move instance e.g. ap5 is split into ap16 and ap17 and ap5 is retired.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for insides! Yes from last 2 years I am getting all dev orgs in AP5 now recently I created is on EU. I am in India & was expecting AP as usually I get.

Comment: @YogeshShukla Are you setting the "Country" field in https://developer.salesforce.com/signup to the same thing? That drives the na/eu selection in my experience as the_phantom describes.

Comment: Ohh. Maybe this time I have selected wrong country in picklist. I earler thought its on web request originating region.

Answer (score 1):

At any given time, each Salesforce instance is served from a specific Data center. However, it is built and serviced from two geographical locations to support the continuous availability and disaster recovery support.

In my experience, I have observed that, when we sign up for a developer org, it is created on the nearest data center to ensure least network latency and provide a seamless experience.
Also, all the transactions in your primary instance replicate in near real-time on the secondary location.

Salesforce have this capability to switch sites between different locations to ensure availability, services and maintenance. As far I remember, there are currently 9 Salesforce data centers across the globe. For example, your "ap" instances are mostly served from Tokyo, Japan.